# Update each sql server row with join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

In each row, i have one column quantities(float) and id(int). So I want with the join to add the sum of quantities with the same id from table1  to table2 quantities in inventory. Example.

My SQL information

```
    Table 1                   Table 2
 id   quantities           id    quantities
 1        1                 1         0  
 1        2                 2         0
 2        4                 3         0 
 2        1         
 3        7
```

I want to sum quantities from table 1 and with join to add it in table 2

Desired result to table 2

```
    Table 1                   Table 2
 id   quantities           id    quantities
 1        1                 1         3  
 1        2                 2         5
 2        4                 3         7
 2        1         
 3        7
```

I'm trying this code, but it adds only first row

```
update i set quantities=i.quantities+sum(s.rent) from inventory i join temp_rent s on i.id=s.itemid
```

Comment: Your code is joining on ID and ItemID, but you don't show that in your tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple JOIN and aggregation should do the trick

```
Update Table2
   set quantities = B.Total
 From  Tabel2 A
 Join (Select ID
             ,Total=sum(quantities)
       From  Table1
       Group By ID
      ) B
  on (A.ID=B.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do...

```
CREATE TABLE #table1 ( id INT, quantities INT)

INSERT INTO #table1(id, quantities)
VALUES (1, 1)   
INSERT INTO #table1(id, quantities)
VALUES (1, 2)       
INSERT INTO #table1(id, quantities)
VALUES (2, 4)       
INSERT INTO #table1(id, quantities)
VALUES (2, 1)       
INSERT INTO #table1(id, quantities)
VALUES (3, 7)       

CREATE TABLE #table2 ( id INT, quantities INT)

INSERT INTO #table2(id, quantities)
VALUES (1, 0)   
INSERT INTO #table2(id, quantities)
VALUES (2, 0)       
INSERT INTO #table2(id, quantities)
VALUES (3, 0)   

UPDATE #table2
SET quantities = t1.quantities
FROM #table2 t2
    JOIN (
            SELECT id, SUM(quantities) AS quantities
            FROM #table1 
            GROUP BY id
        ) t1 ON
        t2.id = t1.id

DROP TABLE #table1
DROP TABLE #table2
```